# 2D collision for games without AABB

Tags: 2d, collision-detection

What exactly is the best way to detect 2d game collision? I use aabb's (axis-aligned-bounding-boxes) but if you have a big circle or something, you will be hitting it when your like 200 pixels away. Would the best way be to just see if the pixels in the 2 images are touching? please let me know a good method.

EDIT:
Ok so now I realize how simple circle collision is. but say I have an oval or something that isn't really a shape. Or even a square that is rotated 45 degrees.

Comment: Use local axes (i.e. make one axis your direction of travel).

Comment: for circles you don't need tan, just (x1-x2)²+(y1-y2)² < r1+r2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have circles you can use Circle-To-Circle collision. Just take the distance of the midpoints and compare it with the length of the radii.
Beside that it really depends on what you need. There's a plethora of collision detection algorithms (mostly to speed things up, e.g. by using coherence between frames) but that's out of the range for a short general note and you'd need to specify your problem a bit more.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I guess the circle thing was pretty obvious.

Comment: Ok, so you look for something that always works, for arbitrary shapes?

Comment: we should discuss this in chat

Comment: No we shouldn't, since a private chat violates the spirit of this site. You should create clearer questions and then people can give clearer answers. This has the benefit that others can find and read the discussion later. For example: You talk about a pixel-wise tolerance, which may indicate that you are trying to do a sprite / mask based collision detection, which is very different from an geometry based approach. In general asking for The Best Way™ can only be answered if you provide enough detail, as there is (usually) no best way for a problem.

Comment: I just said that so this didn't turn into a discussion. SO will sometimes automatically lets you do that. Anyway. when I said best, I meant the method that most people use.